# Tensorflow on Hadoop/Spark using TensorflowOnSpark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, tensorflow

I am new on Spark and Tensorflow and am trying to execute a simple example on a cluster. I use Spark 2.1.0 and Hadoop 2.7.4 (with Spark for Hadoop 2.7)

I have access to a Hadoop/Spark installation on Google Cloud with 3 machines that seems to work fine for other tasks.

I try to execute :

```
${SPARK_HOME}/bin/spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi
--master yarn   --deploy-mode cluster
--driver-memory 1g lib/spark-examples*.jar 10
```

and i get the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.Apps.crossPlatformify(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.MRJobConfig.<clinit>(MRJobConfig.java:695)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.newFieldAccessor(UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.java:43)
  at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newFieldAccessor(ReflectionFactory.java:156)
  at java.lang.reflect.Field.acquireFieldAccessor(Field.java:1088)
  at java.lang.reflect.Field.getFieldAccessor(Field.java:1069)
  at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:393)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$24.apply(Client.scala:1305)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$24.apply(Client.scala:1303)
  at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.getDefaultMRApplicationClasspath(Client.scala:1303)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.getMRAppClasspath(Client.scala:1280)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.populateHadoopClasspath(Client.scala:1265)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.populateClasspath(Client.scala:1380)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.setupLaunchEnv(Client.scala:755)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.createContainerLaunchContext(Client.scala:867)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.submitApplication(Client.scala:170)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1154)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.main(Client.scala:1213)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.main(Client.scala)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:738)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

I know the missing method can be found in hadoop-common-2.7.3.jar
which exists in 
/opt/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/hadoop-common-2.7.3.jar
and /opt/hadoop-2.7.4/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.7.4.jar
for every machine

I have also tried using : --jars and --driver-library-path with the path of the jar but these made no difference.

Executing the above command using --master client(instead of yarn) gives no error(executes just fine).

I suppose it is a configuration problem but am not sure where to look for.